# How can you avoid space around a background color applied on a div?

Tags: html, css, background-color

This is the code I wrote. but it doesn't work as I expected. There is space around the background color still and I want to cover the div with that color.

What is the issue here?

```
#div {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: try removing padding from the div---  div {padding:0}.. also suggest you change the id- a div with the id of 'div' seems wrong :)

Comment: Kindly to provide an code run online editor then point your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be happening for 2 reasons :

1. You don't have initial values set to 0 in CSS for the entire DOM
2. You have some `padding` on a parent element,or `margin` on child element that you need to get rid off

Attaching a runnable snippet for your reference

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border:box
}

.main{
  background:blue;
  padding:1rem;
}

.child{
  background:red;
  padding:1rem;
}

.grandchild{
  background:yellow;
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class=main>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grandchild">
        Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have set the margin value to zero for the entire DOM. And it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`background-color` is not applied on margins. Replace `margin: 0;` with `padding: 0;`